# How do I get the smoke to not spread everywhere?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I want smoke to come out of my chimney and move upwards like a whisp, but it keeps generating in the surrounding area, and spreading outwards far too aggressively. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What does it give if you select the flow object > Flow Source > Volume Emission, decrease the value?